# Send Apple Watch notification to iPhone

Tags: ios, apple-watch

For Objective-C,
is it possible to send notification from iPhone to Apple Watch?
Is the reverse possible?

If yes, please guide me by some code or link.

Comment: Yes. Pretty much all the watch does at this point is send & receive data from related phone apps. https://developer.apple.com/watchkit/

Comment: i done with image and label.but i want like timer value or any value send to iwatch to iphone as local notification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WKInterfaceController has [openParentApplication:reply:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/WKInterfaceController/openParentApplication:reply:) method that can send some user info to parent app and get a response. Also you can use darwin notifications to send messages from iPhone to watch and reverse. Look at [MMWormhole](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMWormhole) to see some examples of code.

Comment: and what about current location iniwatch?

Comment: all code executes on iPhone, so you can use location services without any problem